# Is there any way to get data for 300 row keys(random) from hbase, without using a loops and with minimum hits

Tags: hbase

My Graph DB is returning me row keys lets assume 300 and that are completely random. I want to get data from my HBase table based on these row keys. I don't want to hit hbase for 300 times. Is there any possible way.
I cant use filters because row keys are random.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Htable has a method
public Result[] get(List gets) throws IOException
you should try this.

BTW
I am writing a hbase ORM framework, also provides batch get feature.
https://github.com/zhang-xzhi/simplehbase